# Stuck in Retrieving image from AWS S3

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I kept trying to retrieve image from S3, and there is no error message... but I cannot see the actual image on my page.
I used the express, node.js to make a little application.
Here are my codes.. please help me to fix this....

upload image on S3-----------

```
(req, res, next) => {
const file = req.file; //to get this "file", I used a multer.diskStorage on routes
const fileData = fs.readFileSync(file.path);

const fileName = file.path.substring(8);    

var params = {
Bucket: "test-s3-may",
Key: fileName,
Body: fileData,
ContentType: file.mimetype,
ACL: "public-read"
};

s3.upload(params, function(err, data) 
{if(err) {return next(err);}
```

Retrieve image from S3-----

```
function viewAlbum(filename) {

var params = {"Bucket": 'test-s3-may', 
                    "Key": filename};

s3.getObject(params, function(err, file){

if(err) {return "we got a error";}
else{
var url = "data:image/jpeg;base64,"+ encode(file.Body);
}
return url;   })                
}

function encode(data)
{
    var res = (Buffer.from(data).toString('base64'));
    return res;
}
```

and I used "url" on view with 
`<img src= >`

Is there any problem on uploading?
It is so strange that there is a error message "This is not a supported format" on window explorer
when I download the image file what I uploaded through this app....

Comment: Are your using AWS S3 for node?  Please be more specific in your code example and what problems you're seeing.  Have you following the guides here? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/s3-node-examples.html

Comment: Your url should be something like https://bucket name.s3.amazonaws.com/filename